# How to solve - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror

I have two files, one is the front-end `login.jsp` and the back-end `loginUser.java`. I am trying to get the `boolean` from the `loginUser.java`. However, there come out a error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError`. I have no idea why this come out. How can I solve this error? Thanks.

Here is my code of 'login.jsp':

```
   try{
            out.println("HT");
                  login.LoginUser user = new login.LoginUser(id,pwd);
                  boolean login_success = user.isLogin(); <---This line have error.
                  //int role_id = user.get_role_id();                   
                  if (login_success){
                             out.println("Login Success");
                             // out.println(user.get_role_id().toString());

 %>
 <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "control_panel.jsp"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
        },2000);
 </script>
 <%
   }
    else{
       out.println("Login Failed");

 %>
```

Here is my code of 'loginUser.java':

```
public class LoginUser {

private String username,password;
public boolean login_success;
public int role_id;



public LoginUser(String username,String password){
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.login_success=false;
    this.role_id = 0;
}

public boolean login(){
    db.DataConnect conn = new db.DataConnect();
    conn.connect();

    ResultSet login_result;
    String sql_statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_found, role_id FROM t_user WHERE user_name = '" + this.username + "' AND password = '" + this.password + "'";
    System.out.println(sql_statement);
    try{
        login_result = conn.select(sql_statement);
        if(login_result.next()){
            if(login_result.getInt("user_found") == 1){
                login_success = true;
                role_id = login_result.getInt("role_id");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    conn.close();

    return login_success;
}

public boolean isLogin(){
    return true;
}


 }
```

However, the when I changed the line `boolean login_success = user.isLogin();` to `boolean login_success = user.login();`, the error will not come out.

Answer (score 0):

As the errror clearly says that the class file is **Incompatible**, you can fix the issue by recompiling your source files and then add to the server classpath.

> Thrown when an incompatible class change has occurred to some class
>   definition. The definition of some class, on which the currently
>   executing method depends, has since changed.